# xcode product packaging Metallink

Tags: xcode, macos, metal

I have an xcode project which generates *.metal shaders using a custom build rule.
Somehow xcode tried to automatically compile these generated shaders during the "Process product packaging" build step.
This fails, as these shaders are not meant to be compiled at that point. Is there a way to exclude the build rule outputs from building? If i remove the build rule inputs files from the "Copy Bundle Resources" list, the rule does not get called.
Adding the metal extension to the "Excluded Source File Names" also doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda have a solution for you, but it's not perfect.

Open your project in Xcode. Select the .metal file that's giving you trouble. If you go into File Inspector (View -> Inspectors -> File). There you can either uncheck all the targets under `Target Membership` so that Xcode doesn't try to build it at all. Or you can also try and change it's `Type` to like a text file or something.